# How to implement shiny busy/recalculate loader in ui section and not the whole tabPanel?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I am using js script to show the loader by identifying the shiny busy/recalculate for the datatable and it is working fine, however I want to restrict this only to a particular actionButton in the ui section but unfortunately it is acting for the entire tabPanel which causes the Loader to show for a microsecond when other process in the same tabPanel is working.

Below is the js script for shiny busy and recalculating

```
$(document).on('shiny:recalculating', function() {
   $('div#divLoading').addClass('show');   });

$(document).on('shiny:value shiny:error shiny:idle', function() {
   $('div#divLoading2').removeClass('show');    });
```

and in the UI section I am applying this by adding the id element to the datatables

```
shinyUI( 
fluidPage(

tabPanel("Main", 
dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = ""),
div(id='divLoading'),
DT::dataTableOutput("Prediction.Table"),
actionButton("Submit")
))
)
```

How can I implement shiny busy/recalculate loader in specific ui section and not in the whole tabPanel ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `shinycssloader`.
Following example shows two separate loaders on two different ui objects (plots) :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  shinycssloaders::withSpinner(
    plotOutput("plot1")
  ),
  shinycssloaders::withSpinner(
    plotOutput("plot2")
  )
  
)
server <- function(input, output) {
 
  data <- reactive({
    # Calculations
    req(input$go)
    Sys.sleep(2)
    runif(10)
    })
   output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$go)
    Sys.sleep(1)
    plot(data())
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
      plot(runif(10))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Waldi, I tried shinycssloader before, the problem in this function is that it does not show spinner during the calculation part but only during the plot generation and rendering, also it was not compatible with datatables with huge data.

Comment: Is it possible to show the spinner when data is being processed or specifically when shiny is calculating something ?  I tried with shiny:busy but it catches more events and pops up whenever shiny is doing anything.